# Shrinkwrap modifier on sharp edges

Tags: faces, edges, shrinkwrap, clipping

Why is my shrinkwrap modifier breaking/clipping on sharper edges ? Is there any way to fix this?

[image: Shrinkwrap modifier clipping faces on sharper edges]

Adding subdivisions to both objects, results in no changes.

[image: Shrinkwrap modifier clipping faces on sharper edges after adding additional subdivisions]

Project file:

[image]

Comment: because the vertices stick to the target, not the faces, maybe add some subdivisions to your object?

Comment: Tried adding more subdivisions, no changes in the behaviour. Updated the question with a new picture.

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Added .blend file download in question.

Comment: the Wrap Method > Project works fine, I don't know about the Target Normal Project

Comment: I don't know how to use the project wrap method. However, I just found that increasing the scale of the wrapping object to be larger than the target object fixes the issue for Target Normal Project. The subdivisions are still needed though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not documented, but I suspect the *Project* method with no axis specified, is Source Normal projection...

[image]

... which in this case, from your source cylinder, seems to produce a good result:

[image]